# problem installing memcached on centos 5.4 64 bit

Tags: memcached, centos, centos5

I'm trying to install memcached on Centos 5.4 with:

```
# yum install memcached
```

What I get is:

```
[root@domU-12-31-39-02-75-A8 ~]# yum -y install memcached
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
rightscale-epel                                                                                                                        |  951 B     00:00     
rpmforge                                                                                                                               | 1.1 kB     00:00     
rpmforge/primary                                                                                                                       | 3.9 MB     00:01     
rpmforge                                                                                                                                          10767/10767

Setting up Install Process

Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.5-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libevent-1.4.so.2()(64bit) for package: memcached
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.x86_64 from epel has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libevent-1.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
Error: Missing Dependency: libevent-1.4.so.2()(64bit) is needed by package memcached-1.4.5-1.el5.x86_64 (epel)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I install memcached?

Thanks, Alex A.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it manually or change your `yum` repo:

```
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/dag/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/testing/RPMS/libevent-1.3b-1.el5.test.x86_64.rpm
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/memcached/memcached-1.2.6-1.el3.rf.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh libevent-1.3b-1.el5.test.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh memcached-1.2.6-1.el3.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

Note, that this is an older version of memcached